# Executable created with pyinstaller does not run

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language, kivymd

I developed a system in python using the kivy framework and at the end of the system I went to generate an executable using the pyinstaller. I followed some tutorials and at the end of all the problem is always the same, the executable does not run. No error message is displayed, the system just doesn't run.
Below is the main.spec code for my system. I can't find what is wrong.

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
    ('def_global.py', '.'),
    ('geckodriver.log', '.'),
    ('setup.py', '.'),
    ('setup_old.py', '.'),
    ('server/settings.py', 'server'),
    ('path/server.py', 'path'),
    ('jsons/.campaign_selected.json', 'jsons'),
    ('jsons/.token.json', 'jsons'),
    ('jsons/.user.json', 'jsons'),
    ('img/*.png', 'img'),
    ('drivers/chromedriver.exe', 'drivers'),
    ('drivers/chromedriver_win32.zip', 'drivers'),
    ('drivers/geckodriver.exe', 'drivers'),
    ('drivers/geckodriver.log', 'drivers'),
    ('common/parasite/parasite.py', 'common/parasite'),
    ('common/proxy/proxy.py', 'common/proxy'),
    ('common/tools/*.py', 'common/tools'),
    ('common/tools/debug.log', 'common/tools'),
    ('apps/backup/*.py', 'apps/backups'),
    ('apps/posts/*.py', 'apps/posts'),
    ('apps/server_util/*.log', 'apps/server_util'),
    ('apps/server_util/*.py', 'apps/server_util'),
    ]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\T-Gamer\\Documents\\python\\first_project_kivy\\project_kivy'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               Tree('C:\\Users\\T-Gamer\\Documents\\python\\first_project_kivy\\project_kivy\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

Comment: Your `spec` file will create a `onedir` executable. That means that you must execute the `.exe` that is created from within the created folder. Are you doing that?

Comment: This problem was solved. The solution was change the python's version to 3.6